# How to handle the value which I selected from list on autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, codemirror

I am using codemirror editor ... I need when I do autocomplete and I selected item from drop down list to handle (get) the value selected ... can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do something with the selected item? If so, you should listen to the `pick` event on the `completion` object. You can do it by this:

```
...
var completion = {list: someHintList, from: somePos, to: somePos};
CodeMirror.on(completion, "pick", function(selectedItem) {
  // Do something with the selectedItem.
  // This function would be called after user pick a item from the list.
}
return completion;
```

For more information, please check out the [document about hint addon](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I am using onselect and it work